# Port Forwarding Failing For RabbitMQ in Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm following the Docker documentation on https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/rabbitmq but when I get to port forwarding, I get the following error: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint some-rabbit11 (c8065d91c990ad498501160011a7f264522ddb5f5a1188db934c47853f833fa2): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.17.0.2:15672: input/output error.`

The command I'm trying to run from the terminal is `docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3.6-management`

From what I can find online, the command appears to be correct so I'm not sure what is the root cause.

Comment: Similar issue as https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find out if any docker images use rabbitmq:

   ```
   docker ps -a
   ```
2. Remove any images using docker rabbitmq:

   ```
   docker rm <IMAGE ID>
   ```
3. Restart docker with the system tray app

[image: Restart the docker tray app]

4. Restart docker rabbitmq

   ```
   docker run -d -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3.6-management
   ```

*The management console is exposed on port 15672 and rabbitmq on port 5672*

5. Insure the new instance is running:

   ```
   docker ps
   ```
6. Use the Firefox web-browser. This does not work in Google chrome. Browse to 127.0.0.1:5672

[image: Firexfox]

*This cryptic code shows that rabbit is working.*

Go to 127.0.0.1:15672 to view the management plugin in action. 
*The passwords are defaults*.

Comment: It seems that moving "-p 15672:5672" closer to the front where you have it did the trick